# CSS problems, misalignment, and 100% is not 100%?

Tags: css, width, alignment

I am working on a small project, and am having two tiny problems with CSS.

I have played around with everything to no avail.

1) In IE6 the content and logo is not lining up correctly.

2) In Firefox, the tooltip box fixed at the bottom of the page (which degrades in IE6) although styled as width:100%; is not spanning the whole screen. There is a gap on the left hand side.

These problems can be seen by viewing http://gua.com/wd/ in the respective browsers.

If anyone could advise as to what has gone wrong, and why, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for firefox: Yyou can add `left:0;` for `#bottom`

for internet explorer: I see your menu to be wrong not the logo. To solve this just add `margin:0` for `#top-nav`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. Out of interest, as you clearly know your stuff could you possibly quickly take a look at my CSS and give me your general thoughts..? This is newish to me. Thanks

Comment: in this topic you will read many opinions. One thing you can start use is self-explanatory names for classes and id. Then as the time pass will learn better techniques. I strongly advice you to add firebug plugin for firefox. Will help you a lot in development and debug any future problem (the other browser has developer tools you can check them). Also, when you write css try to take a look in all browsers to check if you code works correctly in all.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using some sort of [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet to overcome specific browser idiosyncrasies.

In your case appending a `margin: 0px;` to your `body` should do the trick (For Firefox). IE6, well, its usually best left to a IE6 specific conditional stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

"100%" means "100% of the parent box's client space". Not "100% of the entire viewport".

And IE6's CSS support is f*cked beyond sanity. If it doesn't work, use absolute positioning or whatever else it takes in a special stylesheet and include it with conditional comments.